# how to install CRM SDK 2016 with VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have VS2013 and I m getting started with CRM development. I have downloaded CRM SDK 2016 and unzip it but it is not containing a msi file. I saw a couple of videos they suggest msi package should be run to make sdk and crm development tools available. Is it not fully supported ? Kindly guide how I can install SDK 2016 with VS 2013.

I'm using [this download for the SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50032).

My purpose is to connect to CRM 2016 online using VS2013 for learning.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find a `vsix` extension for Visual Studio in the `SDK\Templates` folder where you extracted the SDK. It supports Visual Studio 2012, 2013 and 2015.

[image]

When building custom plugins or other projects that reference the CRM API, add [the corresponding NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=dynamics%20crm%202016) to your project.